# Caching DB Result As Global Var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I currently have a helper method that gets `Klass.all.map{|m| m.name}`. Now I use ids to get the name from the array and if I add more it'll automatically update.

When I use this helper method in a loop in the view, I think it will make multiple queries to get the Klass each time which means a lot of extra work.

I was wondering how I can "cache" this array or if I should be doing this a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL caching is done automatically if you're within the same action. You can see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) for a more detailed explanation. Just by the way, it would probably be more efficient to use `pluck`, as in `Klass.pluck(:name)`. This would optimize your SQL query.

Comment: Thanks! I felt like it was being cached. Just wanted some documentation for it.

Comment: Though it caches SQL query, it doesn't cache Ruby objects. This means, that every time you call your helper method a whole new array gets initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper method should look similar to this

```
def klass_names
  @klass_names ||= Klass.all.map{|m| m.name}
end
```